# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using Windows 10 and my python version is 3.7.1.

I uninstalled `pyqt5` and `pyqt5-tools` and then reinstalled them

Then, I import the following packages:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
```

But I received an error:

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'
```

How to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: try with: `python -m pip install PyQt5-sip PyQtWebEngine pyqt5 sip`

Comment: Now, I got the error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWebEngineWidgets' from 'PyQt5' (C:\Users\chan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py)`

Comment: execute: `python -m pip install PyQtWebEngine`. From PyQt 5.12 the module was separated